# How can the second harvest in Revelation 14 be the unrighteous when in every other place it says the second harvest will be the righteous?

Tags: revelation

Matthew 13 and Revelation 14 contradict. Who are the grapes?

Matthew 13

The weeds/tares are gathered first and burned.

> <sup>**30**</sup> Let both grow together until the harvest, and at harvest time I will tell the reapers, “Gather the weeds first and bind them in bundles to be burned, but gather the wheat into my barn.'"

Revelation 14 first harvest

> <sup>**15**</sup> And another angel came out of the temple, calling with a loud voice to him who sat on the cloud, “Put in your sickle, and reap, for the hour to reap has come, for the harvest of the earth is fully ripe.” <sup>**16**</sup> So he who sat on the cloud swung his sickle across the earth, and the earth was reaped.

Revelation 14 depicts the second harvest of grapes being harvested and trodden down outside of the city in the wine press of the wrath of God.

> <sup>**18**</sup> ... "Put in your sickle and gather the clusters from the vine of the earth, for its grapes are ripe.” <sup>**19**</sup> So the angel swung his sickle across the earth and gathered the grape harvest of the earth and threw it into the great winepress of the wrath of God. <sup>**20**</sup> And the winepress was trodden outside the city, and blood flowed from the winepress, as high as a horse's bridle, for 1,600 stadia.

Comment: Perhaps the order does not matter - they occur at the same time??

Comment: . . .  _to be burned_ . . .  the burning does not occur until after the second reaping.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics.SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is not to get too legalistic about the language used in the Bible. These two passages are just using different metaphors to create different ideas.

Matthew ch13 is mainly focussed on salvation, the "gathering in" of the people God wants, so it offers metaphors about collecting good things (from God's viewpoint) or finding good things (from the believer's viewpoint). The harvest from the good seed, like the harvest of fish at the end of the chapter, is in the first group. The rejection of the bad is a secondary issue.

Whereas Revelation ch14 is focussed upon judgment. In fact the passage vv14-20 is simply a dramatised verion of Joel ch3 v13; "Put in the sickle, for the harvest is ripe. Go in, tread, for the wine-press is full. The vats overflow, for their wickedness is very great" (RSV). In that case, the harvest of grapes is there only as a necessary preparation for the wine-press image, which is about the death of the wicked associated with judgment. You can't press out the grapes until you have got them in front of you.

So whenever you see an apparent contradiction in the Bible, you should consider the possibility that words are being used in different ways. It happens.